# Taking two limits vs using a single parameter for both limits

Tags: limits, information-theory

The background comes from information theory. There, one often sees a cost of communication that depends on the blocklength $n$ (how much information can be sent) and the error $\varepsilon$. Specifically, let some communication problem have a cost given by $C(n, \varepsilon)$. The asymptotic limit is usually defined when one first takes the blocklength $n\rightarrow\infty$ and then takes the error $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. Let it hold that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}C(n, \varepsilon) = C,$$

for some constant $C$. If one were to choose a sequence $\varepsilon_n$ where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\varepsilon_n = 0$, then does it also hold that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}C(n, \varepsilon_n) = C?$$

Or do there exist sequences $\varepsilon_n$ that would not satisfy the second equation?

EDIT: Added a missing $1/n$ in the second equation as per the comment.

Comment: Did you intend to have a factor $\tfrac1n$ in the second equation?

Comment: Not for general sequences, e.g. take $a(n,\varepsilon) = 1-1/n\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon_n = 1/n.$ If you're specifically thinking about information theory, then I'm guessing you're interested in the behaviour of $R^*(n,\varepsilon),$ the best rate you can get over a channel with blocklength $n$ and probability of error $\varepsilon$. For this, more or less, it holds that $\lim R^*(n,\varepsilon_n) = C,$ the capacity, iff $\log(1/\varepsilon_n)/\sqrt{n} \to 0.$ See the section on channel dispersion in [this book](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/itbook-export.pdf).